# What does fgets return when EOF is found?

Tags: fgets

does it return anything? is EOF nothing but -1 ? How does fgets detect an EOF ?
Can somebody please elaborate also on the difference between gets and fgets()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns NULL on encountering EOF